# Fatou’s lemma equality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I found a sequence of functions that makes Fatou’s lemma be a strict unequality, but I’m not able to find one that makes it be an equality.
Can you help me to find one?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$S=[0,1]$ , $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure and $f_n=1$ on $S$ for all $n$